# How to add scroll bar in a phonegap application

Tags: android, cordova, scrollbar

I'm developing an application in PhoneGap for the Android platform.

In this app the scroll bar is not displayed. How can I display a scroll bar in my application?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is my example Activity that will display the scrollbars

```
public class MyActivity extends DroidGap {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");

        // Display vertical scrollbar and hide horizontal scrollBar
        super.appView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
        super.appView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        // set scrollbar style
        super.appView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
    }

}
```

Comment: I receive an error: cannot find symbol method setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(boolean) Can you help me ?

Comment: This soln doesn't work. There are errors in all 3 lines added at last. I don't know how it is accepted and got 6 upvotes.

Answer (score 2):

well scrolling is the effect that cannot be seen in phonegap/cordova projects, for that purpose we can there are tools third party libraries that you can include in your project. the one that i used for my project was [iscroll 4](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4) . even this has some problems but that can be solved surfing the google groups of iscroll4
also ther is this [jquery-mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/) that also gives scrolling effect for phonegap projects.

Comment: by default scroll bar is comes in any html data,,,so that means it has to be disply in phonegap also,please be more specfic about ur query,,u don't need to put nay extra library for scroll..i this in ur css file some content got fixed programetically,so plz be some what specfic while asking some question so we can look ahead of it clearly

Comment: @AamirPathan you will get to knw what i'm talking about when u'll come across the problem. you can visit http://code.ign.com/blog/2012/03/09/the-promise-of-html5-and-the-reality-of-android-fragmentation. the thing is there is this overflow:scroll provided in html but it doesnt work in webview so we  cant give it native scroll effect without help of external libraries

Comment: @NejiHyuga  your answer is helpful for me. I've done it. now the scroll bar is showing in my app. Thank you so much for help me.

Answer (score 0):

This solution does not completely solve the problem if you want to use scrolled div inside the main div.

Put others elements in absolute position over the main div.

Try this: [Apache cordova on android where are scrollbars?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21498967/apache-cordova-on-android-where-are-scrollbars)

Answer (score 0):

We have been facing the same issue. Cordova disables scroll bars on the web view in `CordovaWebView.java`, so we created a [plugin](http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/de.mayflower.cordova.android-scrollbar) that allows you to reenable the vertical scrollbar programmatically from JavaScript without hacking up Cordova:

```
mayflower.AndroidScrollbar.toggleVerticalScrollbarVisibility(true)
.then(
    function() {
        console.log('Vertical scrollbar enabled');
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using Cordova 5.2+ and facing the same challenge. But, I found the solution here:

- You can go to: *SystemWebViewEngine.java* which located in
  yourAppName\platforms\android\CordovaLib\src\org\apache\cordova\SystemWebViewEngine.java
- Then, set:

  webView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);

Hope it helps Pal!