# Apache cordova on android where are scrollbars?

Tags: android, scrollbar, cordova-3

I try to build a simple app with cordova which target android

I just want to have a scrollable div but

- if the content is smaller than the div's height, the scrollbar is always visible
- if the content is bigger than the div's height, the scrollbar never appear, even if I scroll : the scroll is possible but no scrollbar position indication

My layout is simple :

```
<body>
    <div id='views'>
        <div class='view'>
            Lorem ipsum ...
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Css is simple too :

```
#views {
    position : absolute;
    top:0; right:0; bottom:0; left:0;
}

.view {
    position : absolute;
    top:0; right:0; bottom:0; left:0;
    overflow-x                 : hidden;
    overflow-y                 : scroll;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling : touch;
    overflow-scrolling         : touch;
}
```

Then I use command : cordova run android

note :

- I use cordova version 3.3.1-0.3.1
- test on Nexus 7 updated (android kitkat)
- with last android API : 19

Thanks for your help

edit : I just try with iOs simulator (iOS 6.1), the scrollbars are visibles when I scroll ...

[updated]
Thanks to help me.
Here is is the correct code to have scrollbars on android

[updated 2]
It's not totally ok, try this, the whole window scroll, not only the .view content

HTML

```
<body>
    <div id='views'>
        <div class='view'>
            Lorem ipsum ...
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id='menu-bt'></div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
.view {
    position:absolute;
    top:0; right:0; bottom:0; left:0;
    overflow:visible;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;
    overflow-scrolling:touch;
}

#menu-bt {
    position:absolute;
    right:40px; bottom:40px;
    width:50px; height:50px;
    background-color:green;
}
```

Then, add this line in file /plateforms/android/src/io/cordova/myProject/MyProject.java

```
super.appView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 2):

Tested here and changing your overflows to `visible` it works.

Also, make sure to enable the scrollbars in your Android Activity file (as pointed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10684066/how-to-add-scroll-bar-in-a-phonegap-application)) by adding the following line:

```
super.appView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it works ! I updated my question with the new code

Comment: unfortunately, it's not totally ok, just try to add button in absolute position and you'll understand what I mean, with your solution, the whole window scroll, not only the content of div view :(
I add the example in my question

Comment: for newer versions of cordova use:
`appView.getView().setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);`

Answer (score 0):

Go to: *SystemWebViewEngine.java* which located in
yourAppName\platforms\android\CordovaLib\src\org\apache\cordova\SystemWebViewEngine.java

Set `webView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);`